# Creating two tables while selecting the top row from the previously created table

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I would like to know more about inserting into one table a value right after creating the first one,

**Scenario**:

I have two tables `Patient` with `PID` as the PK, and the `PatientRecord` with `RID` as the PK and `PID` as a FK to `Patient`.

What I want to do is to insert the latest `PID` into the `PatientRecord` right after successfully creating it.

Initial SQL:

```
INSERT INTO record (@PID,@NID,@DID)
values((SELECT TOP (1) PERCENT 'PID' FROM patient),2,1)
```

*The values 2, and 1 do already exist inside the `Doctor` and `Nurse` tables.*

I realize that I am making a huge mistake with that query, but with a little help of explanation about where did i go wrong and/or a direct guidance will help a lot.

Code snippets will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use an identity field for the primary key in the patient table. Then you can use something like..

`insert into Patient values ('some patient values')`

`insert into PatientRecord values (ident_current('Patient'), 'some patient record values')`

Comment: IDENT_CURRENT... thanks a lot! your answer definitely helped :), sadly cant raise your reputation as i dont have enough points.